# Using the already-defined regex pattern in another regex pattern and a question about applying regex to file

Tags: c++, regex, file

How can I use the already-defined regex pattern in another regex pattern. For example in the following code `sign` and `number` are defined and I want to use them in defining `relation`:

```
regex sign("=<|=|>|<=|<>|>=");
regex number("^[1-9]\\d*");
regex relation(number, sign, number)
```

So, I need to find all matches (to the pattern like `23<=34` or `123<>2000`) in the given *file*.

Since I haven't completed the `relation`, I've been testing with `sign`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  regex sign("=<|=|>|<=|<>|>=");
  regex digit("[0-9]");
  regex number("^[1-9]\\d*"); 
  //regex relation("^[1-9]\d*[=<|=|>|<=|<>|>=]^[1-9]\d*"); (this part is what I couldn't do)

  string line;

  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("name.txt");

  if (fin.good()) {
    while (getline(fin, line)) {
      bool match_sign = regex_search(line, sign);
      if (match_sign) {
        cout << line << endl; // but I need to print the match only
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;

}
```

When I want to print the matches in the file, it prints the whole line which contains any match. How can I make it print only the match itself but not the whole line?

---

**Update:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
#define REGEX_SIGN   "=<|=|>|<=|<>|>="
#define REGEX_DIGIT  "[0-9]"
#define REGEX_NUMBER "^" REGEX_DIGIT "\\d*"

int main() {
  regex sign(REGEX_SIGN);
  regex digit(REGEX_DIGIT);
  regex number(REGEX_NUMBER); 
  regex relation(REGEX_NUMBER REGEX_SIGN REGEX_NUMBER);
  string line, text;

  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("name.txt");

  if (fin.good()) {

    while (getline(fin, line)) {
      text += line + " ";
    }

    int count = 0;
    string word = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {

      if (text[i] == ' ') {
        cout << "word = " << word << " | match: " << regex_match(word, relation) << endl;
        if (regex_match(word, relation)) {
          cout << word << endl;
        }

        word = "";
      } 
      else {
        word += text[i];
      }
    }
  }
  // cout << text << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Current `name.txt` looks like this:

---

[image]

---

But I think the regular expression is not working right:

---

[image]

---

It says no word matches. Where is the problem?

Comment: Regarding "smth wrong with backslash d", you have to remember that backslash in strings means something special. If you need an explicit backslash inside a string you need to escape it with a backslash, or use "raw" string literals.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, thanks, the error disappeared after adding another backslash there. I will update the question with this correction

Comment: Final string might be [`R"(([1-9]\d*)(<|<=|=|>|>=|<>)([1-9]\d*))"`](https://regex101.com/r/bCRNl3/1).

Answer (score 1):

The problem of "reusing" a smaller regex inside a larger regex is not really possible.

The only workaround I can see is to define the strings of the regexes as macros, and use the compilers literal-string concatenation feature to create larger strings:

```
#define REGEX_SIGN   "=<|=|>|<=|<>|>="
#define REGEX_DIGIT  "[0-9]"
#define REGEX_NUMBER "^" REGEX_DIGIT "\\d*"

regex sign(REGEX_SIGN);
regex digit(REGEX_DIGIT);
regex number(REGEX_NUMBER); 
regex relation(REGEX_NUMBER REGEX_SIGN REGEX_NUMBER);
```

This doesn't reuse the actual `regex` objects, only create longer literal strings from smaller.

Comment: I updated the question with your script, but it still seems something is not working right. I attached the output screenshot. There, the first and the third linehad to be `match: 1`...

Comment: `REGEX_SIGN` should be `"(?:=<|=|>|<=|<>|>=)"` to allow meaningful concatenation. and `"^"` should not be in `REGEX_NUMBER`

Comment: @Jarod42 Something like that. :) At least the principle behind the workaround should be clear.